# Python-Tkinter,Combobox - Passing 2 parameters using Lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, combobox

**Background:**

A GUI table having a "skip combobox" widget allowing user to skip current line from executing. Amount of lines in this GUI varies. This "skip" is created using a for loop.

When selecting "on" or "off" a `bind` process executes a method called `self.but_callback` which doing the rest of code.

**goal:**

Pass `i` value to `self.but_callback`, along with `event` needed to `bind`.

Code below, shows a try to pass `i` value directly into `self.but_callback(event,i)` **BUT** instead of assigning the right `i` value it passes the last value of for loop for every `skip_button` created.

**Question:** How to pass correct `i` value while in a loop, when 2 parameters are need to pass using `lambda` function.

> Did not find any answer combining both issues.

```
   for i in range(len(data_from_file)):

        #Skip button
        self.var.append(tk.StringVar())
        self.var[7].set('On')
        skip_button = ttk.Combobox(inner_frame, width=5, textvariable=self.var[7], values=['On','Off'],state='readonly', justify=tk.CENTER)
        skip_button.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',lambda event: self.but_callback(event,i))
        skip_button.grid(row=i+1, column=7, padx=8)


   def but_callback(self,event,x):
        print(x)
```

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? There are likely hundreds of questions with answers related to creating widgets in a loop.

Comment: Yes I did!, and none of what I've found didn't explain how to pass additional parameter to the method.

Comment: I'll be happy if you can share such example, instead of -1, since I've been looking for that answer for almost a day @BryanOakley

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+button+loop+lambda

Comment: @BryanOakley-  I need to pass 2 parameters, `event` and `i`..

Comment: `lambda event, x=i : self.but_callback(event, x)`

Comment: BTW: `lambda in loop` is common problem - there are many questions and answers on SO and internet.

Comment: @furas thank you for both answers. The thing that was missing was to defing `i=x`. please post it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very common problem with `lambda` in loop.

It doesn't copy value from `i` when you create `lambda` function but it keeps reference to `i`. So all functions have reference to the same variable (the same place in memory) and they get value from `i` when they are exceuted.

You have to assign `i` to argument in `lambda` (for example `x=i`) and use this argument `x` in your function. This way it will copy current value from `i` and use in `lambda` function

```
lambda event, x=i : self.but_callback(event, x)
```